# Collections and Folders in Google Docs v3 APIs?

Tags: filesystems, google-drive-api, google-docs

The Google Docs v3 APIs do not deal in folders, but rather collections, which allow a many-to-many relationship. However, the API can be used to access files and folders on Google Drive. Because Google Drive has to emulate a file system on the user's hard disk, does this mean that, if I'm using The Google Docs v3 APIs to access files or folders on Google Drive, each folder and file will only have one parent? And if not, can I find an object's local-filesystem parent using the google docs v3 APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Google Docs v3 API is officially deprecated and [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/) replaces it.

Second, Google Drice doesn't fully emulate a file system and one file can have multiple parents.

Third, I'm not 100% sure about what you mean by "local filesystem", but you can access list of object's parents with [Parents.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/list). However, you cannot access any information about user's local filesystem that is synchronized with Drive sync client.

Fourth, for most of the time, each object has only one parent. Please make some assumption by, for example, always choosing first parent like `Parents.list()[0]`

Comment: That answers my question. It creates more problems for me, but ones outside the scope of this question. Thanks.